# TypeScript syntax error when using 'as' cast without semicolon

Tags: typescript

I prefer coding style without semicolons. The following snippet gives me an error:

```
let x = 123
(window as any).test = 'hello'
```

The error is:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.`

If I put a semicolon at the end of the first line it compiles without an error.

I thought that a newline character should be enough for TS to parse those statements separately. Maybe I don't know something, maybe it's a bug? I'd like to know the explanation, please.

**EDIT:** In the accepted answer from the provided link it's stated that ASI occurs in case of `var` statement. Which makes me think that the same applies to `let` and `const`.

So, we have a `var` statement and a `LineTerminator` and according to this TS should parse these two lines as two statements, not one. Where am I wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/6680611

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) - try the same thing in JavaScript (without the `as any`, of course) and you'll get the same result.

Comment: @JoeClay, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the ECMAScript spec, with my emphasis added:

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token (called the offending token) is encountered **that is not allowed by any production of the grammar**, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true...

An expression such as `123` followed by a set of parentheses *is* an allowed production of the grammar - it's a function call!

The parser sees `123(` and thinks you're trying to call `123` as a function, so it throws an error. This is hinted at by the message you get - it's saying that `Number` doesn't have a type definition for when you call it.